# Field can only be defined once graphql

Tags: graphql, express-graphql, typegraphql, graphql-federation

I have 2 subgraphs

[image]

I have this code in the subgraph for template and fileserver

[image]

I call buildFederatedSchema 2 time since I have 2 subgraphs in the server list this the code in modified buildFederatedSchema

[image]

gives me this error what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If someone have an issue like this one in the future, please check on singular and plural how it is defined in your app.

E.g if I added a collection with name events, then create a mutation called createEvent, I might probably need to make changes to the mutation to be createEvents.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue you might have duplicated value on the Graphql definition.

remove on of them

example

```
query GetUsers {
    users {
       username
       full_name
       full_name # remove duplication
       email      
    }
}
```